# ASP.NET - %2F (forward slash) percent-encoded character in route parameter does not get decoded

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, urlencode

I have the following simple controller that just takes a string in the route parameter and returns it as is:

```csharp
[HttpGet("string/{value}")]
public ActionResult Echo([FromRoute] string value)
{
    return new JsonResult(new { output = value });
}
```

It works fine when I provide any percent-encoded character except "%2F" in the string, i.e. it returns it's corresponding string representation:

```
/string/%21%23%28 -> { "output": "!#(" }
```

However, for %2F, it seems it returns the percent-encoded string itself, rather than the corresponding forward-slash character, i.e. "/":

```
/string/%2F -> { "output": "%2F" }
```

How can I ask it to return "/" in the output instead of "%2F"?

Comment: Do you think /string// is going to be valid url?

Comment: I'm not really sure on what you're trying to achieve, but bear in mind that the get http protocol has a lot of "interpretation" (in lack of a better word) going around, for instance a + is always a space (even if you meant a +) so why stick to a HttpGet?

Comment: @Serge I'm expecting the value route parameter to possibly contain a forward slash so I want asp.net to properly decode it before putting it in the variable. It does correctly decode all the other reserved characters just not the %2F one.

Comment: A middleware which can access `HttpContext` or `RouteBuilder` could do the trick in theory... I'm currently trying to figure out if it's really accessible or not.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
value=value.Replace("%2F","/")
return new JsonResult(new { output =  value });
```

Comment: Isn't there no way to ask asp.net to correctly decode it rather than having to perform a manual string replace?

Comment: @Dastan What is the difference for you? You should be happy that it doesn't return 404 like it is in the most cases with back slash. You  are not supposed to use it as an input parameter.

Comment: I understand @Dastan request, which can be legitimate in very specific cases. I recently encoutered one of them (an item code which is provided by an external entity - I can't control the way it's created). The best thing to do would be to create a kind of middleware to intercept the route parameter before it's transmitted to the api method and update the route parameter value.... I haven't managed to build it yet.